# Object not found issue

Tags: r, foreach, forecasting, parallel.foreach, doparallel

I have an issue that has been driving me insane for the last couple hours.

I am using the following packages in R: `forecast`, `fracdiff`, `doParallel`, `foreach` and others. I also have the following function.

```
doparPredictions <- function(train, test, cl){
    training = train
    pred = foreach (i = 1:length(test), .combine=c) %dopar% {
        if (i > 1) {
            training = c(train,test[1:i-1])
        }
        fit = nnetar(training, 8, P=1, 5)
        forecast(fit, 1)$mean
    }
}
```

... and the above function WORKS!

However, if I replace `nnetar(training, 8, P=1, 5)` with `fracdiff(training, 3, 1, h=0.00001)` the function starts failing with the following error.

```
Error in { : task 1 failed - "object 'training' not found"
```

Here is where it gets interesting. It is not actually failing on the edited line. It is actually failing on the next line: `forecast(fit, 1)$mean`

In otherwords, the following DOES in fact work.

```
fits = foreach (i = 1:length(test)) %dopar% {
    if (i > 1) {
        training = c(train,test[1:i-1])
    }
    fracdiff(training, p, q, h=0.00001)
}
```

but then...

```
pred = foreach (i = 1:length(test), .combine=c) %dopar% {
    forecast(fits[[i]], 1)$mean
}
```

throws the previously mentioned error about `"object 'training' not found"`

EDIT: As per request... a reproducable example...

```
require(quantmod)
require(forecast)
require(fracdiff)
require(doParallel)
require(foreach)

cl <- makeCluster((detectCores() - 1), type="FORK")
registerDoParallel(cl)

predictionsThatWork <- function(train, test, cl){
    training = train
    pred = foreach (i = 1:length(test), .combine=c) %dopar% {
        if (i > 1) {
            training = c(train,test[1:i-1])
        }
        fit = nnetar(training, 8, P=1, 5)
        forecast(fit, 1)$mean
    }
    return(pred)
}

predictionsThatDoNotWork <- function(train, test, cl){
    training = train
    pred = foreach (i = 1:length(test), .combine=c) %dopar% {
        if (i > 1) {
            training = c(train,test[1:i-1])
        }
        fit = fracdiff(training, 3, 1, h=0.00001)
        forecast(fit, 1)$mean
    }
    return(pred)
}

ticker = 'IBM' #feel free to replace with ticker of your choice
getSymbols(ticker, from='2010-01-01', to='2016-08-31')
fullts = get(ticker)
returnTS = diff(log(fullts[,4]),lag=1)[-1]
returnTS = returnTS - mean(returnTS)
numObs = length(returnTS)
cutOff = ceiling(numObs*.85)
train = returnTS[1:cutOff-1]
test = returnTS[cutOff:numObs]

predictionsThatWork(train, test, cl)
predictionsThatDoNotWork(train, test, cl)

stopCluster(cl)
```

EDIT 2: Ok, this issue has nothing to do with the parallelism. This has everything to do with the interaction between `fracdiff` and `forecast`. The following function does NOT work either

```
anotherBrokenFunction <- function(train, test) {
    training = train
    print(exists('training'))
    predictions = test
    for (i in 1:length(test)){
        print(exists('training'))
        arf = fracdiff(x=training, nar=3, nma=1, h=0.00001)
        print(exists('training'))
        predictions[i] = forecast(arf, 1)$mean
        print(exists('training'))
        training = c(training, test[i])
    }
    return(predictions)
}
```

It evaluates to the following

```
> anotherBrokenFunction(train, test)
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'training' not found
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example please?

Comment: I have made the requested edit

Comment: @WeihuangWong, I have made another update. See above. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a hacky fix, but one suggestion is to add `arf$x <- training` to the function:

```
anotherBrokenFunction <- function(train, test) {
    training = train
    predictions = test
    for (i in 1:length(test)){
        arf = fracdiff(x=training, nar=3, nma=1, h=0.00001)
        arf$x <- training # add this
        predictions[i] = forecast(arf, 1)$mean
        training = c(training, test[i])
    }
    return(predictions)
}

out <- anotherBrokenFunction(train, test)
str(out)
# An ‘xts’ object on 2015-09-02/2016-08-31 containing:
#   Data: num [1:252, 1] -0.000312 -0.000534 0.001913 0.000513 -0.000467 ...
#  - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#   ..$ : NULL
#   ..$ : chr "IBM.Close"
#   Indexed by objects of class: [Date] TZ: UTC
#   xts Attributes:  
# List of 2
#  $ src    : chr "yahoo"
#  $ updated: POSIXct[1:1], format: "2016-09-15 09:56:46"
```

Details: `forecast.fracdiff` calls `getResponse`, and the `fracdiff` method of `getResponse` looks like this:

```
getAnywhere("getResponse.fracdiff")
# A single object matching ‘getResponse.fracdiff’ was found
# It was found in the following places
#   registered S3 method for getResponse from namespace forecast
#   namespace:forecast
# with value

# function (object, ...) 
# {
#     if (is.element("x", names(object))) 
#         x <- object$x
#     else x <- eval.parent(parse(text = as.character(object$call)[2]))
#     if (is.null(tsp(x))) 
#         x <- ts(x, frequency = 1, start = 1)
#     return(x)
# }
# <bytecode: 0x7fd64bd8b698>
# <environment: namespace:forecast>
```

so it looks first for an element named "x" in the `fracdiff` object, failing which it will look for `as.character(object$call)[2]` (which happens to be `training` in this case), which generates the error.  The idea is to insert `training` as the element `x` in the `fracdiff` object to preempt this error.

Comment: Thank you, I had a different workaround, but this one is better. Thanks.

Comment: The latest github version should fix this problem.